# Who composed Ka Keili?

Tags: chagim-holidays, tefilla, song-poetry, history

Who composed Ka Keili? What is the earliest source for this song?

Comment: The question would be much improved if you'd include what you know about it: specifically, where you came across the song.

Comment: What is Ka Keili?

Comment: @AdamMosheh It is a piyut customarily recited before Musaf on Yom Tov (specifically, after the Haftara and before Ashrei), unless Yizkor is recited. It is found at least as far back as [in the siddur](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22560&st=&pgnum=281) of the [Shlah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz).

Answer (score 3):

[The identity of the author is unknown.](http://www.piyut.org.il/textual/272.html)

Comment: piyut.org.il is a wonderful site, but some of their attributions are wrong.  I would not take them as the final word on authorship.